# Missing qt module script on (K)ubuntu 19.04

Tags: package, qt5, ubuntu-19.04

Since an updates I'm not able to compile my Qt code for my Desktop environment. Qmake tells me

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: script

Does anyone know, which package I need to install on Ubuntu 19.04 to enable the script module for Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue in Ubuntu 18.04, Qt 5.
It can be solved by installing the `qtscript5-dev` package:

```
sudo apt-get install qtscript5-dev
```